# Is there any template engine for node.js express quitely like JSP?

Tags: node.js, jsp, express, tiles, template-engine

I need a real jsp-mode template engine, not like jade and ejs:

1. just put a new page file in the webpage folder, type it's uri in browser, it will come to show
2. delete this page file, and it will gone
3. and support `<%include %>` like jsp (support query params)

if more fortune, it would support tile like apache tile. in apache tiles, i can write a template page like

```
main.jsp:
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<tiles:insertTemplate template="/layout/simple.jsp">
  <tiles:putAttribute name="header"  value="/common/header.jsp" />
  <tiles:putAttribute name="left" value="/common/leftmenu.jsp" />
  <tiles:putAttribute name="body" value="<%= request.getParameter("body")%>" />
  <tiles:putAttribute name="footer"   value="/common/footer.jsp" />
</tiles:insertTemplate>
```

now type `main.jsp?body=content1.jsp`, you will saw content.jsp appear inside main.jsp, dress layout/simple.jsp.

I can do all above runtime, need not restart webserver.

Answer (score 3):

ejs is probably the closest thing.
https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

./views/account

```
<% if (user) { %>
    <h2><%= user.name %></h2>
<% } %>
```

./routes/account.js:

```
   res.render('account', { user: user });
```

Comment: hi, in ejs, i should put what file in the folder like jsp, without add route declare statement?

Answer (score 0):

I've neerly implement this. lets add something in the ejs example in express. https://github.com/visionmedia/express

modify index.js, first import vm and fs

```
var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs'), 
    vm = require('vm');
```

then, route all *.shtml (any extension as you will)

```
app.get('*.shtml', function(req, res){
  var url = req._parsedUrl.pathname;
  url = url.substring(1, url.length - 6);
  //console.log(req);
  var jsPath = 'controllers/' + url + '.js';
  //console.log('jsPath ' + jsPath);
  if(fs.existsSync(jsPath)){
      var code = fs.readFileSync(jsPath);
      var context = vm.createContext({req : req, res : res, url : url, console : console});
      vm.runInContext(code, context, jsPath);
  } else {
      res.render(url, req.query);
  }  
});
```

now, test.

node index.js, now we are in runtime.

put a new file named test.html in views

```
test.html:

<% include header.html %>

<h1>Test</h1>

<% include footer.html %>
```

type `test.shtml?title=Test Page`, so this page turn to show. and query param *title* bind within header.html.

well, but we can do less in the page, for the render is controled by the res.render(). if we want to do something before render, or direct output something but not html content, lets have a look.

create a folder named controllers, then create a file named test.js.

```
test.js
console.log('do something....');
res.render(url, req.query);
```

type `test.shtml?title=Test Page` again, you will see test.js output 'do someting....' on the console, and then it render the same-name page in your browser.

all the controller js and html files are all dynamic~~~

thus the theme mode is not very closely to Apache Tiles yet. :(